# License for package Android SDK Platform 23 not accepted

Tags: android, sdk

Trying to `react-native run-android` but got this:

**You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].**

All licenses have been accepted with `sdkmanager --licenses`. How do I fix this?

---

Solution: Deleted `/Users/WHATEVER-YOUR-NAME-IS/Library/Android`, then reinstalled all SDKs through Android Studio's SDK Manager.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Your-Sdk-home-Directory/tools/bin

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

Accept the licences pending.

If still doesn't work, try installin the 23.0.1 or which it is asking for 
Go to Your-Sdk-home-Directory/tools

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.1,android-23,extra-android-m2repository
```

That worked for me..

if it's still giving any issues.
Give a try with
-keeping the licences folder in both sdk home directory and tools/bin directory

-run

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;23.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android Studio installed, open Tools -> SDK Manager, enable the checkbox with the desired version, accept the lisence agreement and install.