# Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 not accepted

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

```
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in /opt/android-sdk/licenses
```

Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /opt/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
/home/geek/projects/MyNotes/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
    information.
```

Comment: Tried to add the answer as a comment, but not enough rep. The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662413/license-for-package-android-sdk-platform-23-not-accepted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [License for package Android SDK Platform 23 not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662413/license-for-package-android-sdk-platform-23-not-accepted)