# React Native: How to currently accept all license agreements on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run `react-native run-android` and I get this error message:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':RNSwipeView'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

I tried going to the link provided which redirected me to a more current link provided which instructed me to go to  **Tools > Android > SDK Manager**. I did not find that in the current project I am working on:
And you can see for yourself:

[image]

So I decided to open a brand new project and I did find the **SDK Manager**:

[image]

Where in there is there a box to tick off license agreements? I could not locate one.

I have also tried the following:

I was able to supposedly accept licenses this way:

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
➜  bin ./sdkmanager --licenses
Warning: File /Users/danale/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

When I tried running `react-native run-android`, I got the same error again.

So I tried it this way according to this answer ([Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)):

```
✗ yes | sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
Password:
Warning: File /var/root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

Ran `react-native run-android` and continued to get the same error you see above.

I tried following Sarats answer:
[License for package Android SDK Platform 23 not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662413/license-for-package-android-sdk-platform-23-not-accepted)

only to be met with this error:

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
"android" SDK commands can be translated to sdkmanager commands on a best-effort basis.
Continue? (This prompt can be suppressed with the --use-sdk-wrapper command-line argument
or by setting the USE_SDK_WRAPPER environment variable) [y/N]: /usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/android: line 118: ${trysdkresponse,,}: bad substitution
Invalid or unsupported command "update sdk"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

How can I accept these license agreements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accept license agreements from command line. Navigate to sdkmanager.
`~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin` Than run sdkmanager `./sdkmanager --licenses` and accept the licenses you need. You can read more information about sdkmanager [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

Comment: I followed these instructions, in fact, I think you have provided this answer in the past. If you look in my OP, you will see where I posted how I followed your steps, only to be met with the same error when running `react-native run-android` again.

Comment: In fact, just for the heck of it, I decided to execute the above command one more time, only to get this answer: `All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...`, but I am still getting the same error when I attempt to run `react-native run-android`.

Comment: Honestly I find this answer here: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/527

There are other options for this problem, I think You can find for Yourself something valuable. Good Luck :)

Comment: thanks, but none of that was helpful either. I tried them all.